# Mapbox getSource return object returns undefined values

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am calling the `getSource` method inside a `load` event like so:

```
map.on('load', () => {

map.addSource("country-boundary-source", {
    type: "vector",
    url: "mapbox://mapbox.country-boundaries-v1"
});

const source = map.getSource("country-boundary-source");

console.log("Source:", source);

})
```

In the output, the object has fields such as `vectorLayers` and `vectorLayerIds`. However when I call these values using `source.vectorLayers` I get an undefined value returned to me. I'm not really sure why this would be happening, since it is being outputted.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to access those values, but I dont understand why they are undefined.